# Remote connect adb to android device

Tags: adb, wi-fi, bluetooth, ssh, wireless-debugging

How can I use adb shell for an android device wireless and remotely? With ssh, wifi, or bluetooth. For example can I connect to my mobile from laptop with bluetooth and use adb shell in laptop for my mobile?

Comment: ADB is a plaintext protocol without any transport encryption or protection. Because of this it is not recommended to use it remotely (e.g. through Internet) as command injection would be easy on the adb connection.

Comment: @Robert You are right, but I want to do it almost once. I do not think there is a dangerous risk for a short connection.

Comment: wireless adb is IPv4 based and does not work remote

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you, but it would be better if there is no need to android studio

Comment: All that you need is `adb` binary, not Android Studio.

Comment: @IrfanLatif This is a part of the guide:
Before you begin using wireless debugging, you must complete the following steps:
1. ...
2. ...
3. Ensure that you have Android Studio Bumblebee. You can download it here.
4. ...